# Git log outputs in a specific revision range

Tags: git, git-log

Here is my problem. How could I get all log messages between 2 revision numbers for a specific path ? let me explain via example.

I tried to write it with this line :

```
git -dir=/home/Desktop/GIT_REFERENCE_REPOSITORIES/manager.git log  10000...15000
```

I assumed it gives me the log messages related to manager.git between 10000 and 15000 revisions. But it doesn't. Is there anyone to help me ?

Comment: History isn't always linear in git - what do you want to happen if there were merges?

Comment: what does it give instead i.e. what are you missing or what gets printed that you didn't expect??

Comment: @eckes getting this message

fatal: ambiguous argument '35993...37502': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: please edit your answer with this comment. BTW: it's only TWO dots, not three...

Comment: @CarlNorum I'll try to use this script in linear case

Comment: Are you intending the 10000 and 15000 to represent hashes?

Comment: yea @CarlNorum svn additcs

Comment: always used the two dots. but https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html tells me that there is also a three-dot flavour which behaves totally different...

Comment: Sorry, what does "additcs" means?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A revision is specified by its SHA1 hash.

If you want to see commits for specific files, you have to separate paths with `--`:

```
git log oldhash..newhash -- path/to/inspect
```

does this.

Also note that you are using three dots (`...`) to specify the range. **Usually, you only want two dots**.

Three dots might not give the result you'd expect. As the [man page for gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) (section *SPECIFYING RANGES*) says, while

```
git log a..b
```

means *give me all commits that were made since `a`, until and including `b`* (or, like the man page puts it "Include commits that are reachable from b but exclude those that are reachable from a"), the three-dot variant

```
git log a...b
```

means "Include commits that are reachable from either a or b but exclude those that are reachable from both", which is a totally different thing.

Comment: So `a..b` is like an inner join and `a...b` is the everything that is not in `a..b` :-) I think I finally understand it

Comment: Does not work if the commit path contains some merge commits.

Comment: @RobinHsu there's `--no-merges` which skips merge commits

Comment: So `diff <(git log HEAD~3..HEAD) <(git log HEAD...HEAD~3)` doesn't give a result. Wow.