# Filter git commits by range of hash

Tags: git, git-log

I need to filter commits by a range definded by his own hash number. I've been looking for on internet and I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595305/git-log-outputs-in-a-specific-revision-range

Comment: it is indeed a duplicate, note that "revision number"="hash number"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git log outputs in a specific revision range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595305/git-log-outputs-in-a-specific-revision-range)