# GitHub: List a Range of Commits by Hash

Tags: github, hash, commit

Is there a way on GitHub to show a range of commits filtered by hashes? I know it can be done using dates: `<reponame>/commits?since=<startdate>,until=<enddate>`. I'd like to see all commits starting from a specific hash until another specified hash.

Note: This is *not* a question about [how to list a range of commits with the `git` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595305), but about the [GitHub website](https://github.com/).

It is possible to do when comparing between two branches: `<reponame>/compare/branch1...branch2` (though preferably without the diffs). I would think it would be possible with `<reponame>/compare/starthash...endhash`, <del>but that doesn't work</del> *(see my answer)*.

The docs give info on [comparing between commits](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/comparing-commits) & [getting file history](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/differences-between-commit-views). But I haven't found anything on filtering the history by hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about `<reponame>/compare/starthash...endhash`. I was putting the hashes in the wrong order. It does work. But it does also include diffs. Not sure if there is a way to exclude them.